# Making continue statement work in a do while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while, continue

I need help making my continue statement work in a do-while loop. If the time of day is not valid, I want to ignore the number of cards and just move to the next iteration of the loop. 
Right now, if I do not input 'Morning', 'Afternoon', or 'Evening' for 'time', the loop ends.

Here is my code:

```js
// DECLARE VARIABLES
var time; // timestamp on batch
var count; // number of cards in batch
var repeat; // whether or not the program will repeat
var m = 0; // initial number of Morning cards
var a = 0; // initial number of Afternoon cards
var e = 0; // initial number of Evening cards
var total = 0; // initial number of all cards

//START LOOP
do {
  time = prompt("Is the batch's timestamp 'Morning', 'Afternoon' or 'Evening'?"); // Input value for time
  count = prompt("How many cards are in this batch?"); // Input value for count
  count = parseFloat(count); // return 'count' as a number

  total = total + count; // calculate total number of cards

  if (time == "Morning") {
    m = m + count; // if time is 'Morning', add the # of the cards from this batch to the # of cards from all 'Morning' batches
  } else if (time == "Afternoon") {
    a = a + count; // if time is 'Afternoon', add the # of the cards from this batch to the # of cards from all 'Afternoon' batches
  } else if (time == "Evening") {
    e = e + count; // if time is 'Evening', add the # of the cards from this batch to the # of cards from all 'Evening' batches
  } else {
    continue;
  }

  repeat = prompt("Do you have more batches to enter? Enter 'Y' or 'N'"); // User chooses whether to end the loop
} while (repeat == "Y");

// DISPLAY RESULTS
document.write("Total number of cards: " + total + "<br/>");
document.write("Morning cards: " + m + "<br/>");
document.write("Afternoon cards: " + a + "<br/>");
document.write("Evening cards: " + e);
```

PS: This is for my computer class. This is our activity: 
"In this assignment you will be pseudo-coding an algorithm that accumulates customer survey cards by time of day. You will need to ask for input from the user for time of day (morning, afternoon, and evening) and the number of cards in that batch. The user needs to be able to enter multiple batches for the same time of the day. You will need to use separate accumulators in your loop to keep track of the cards as the loop continues its iterations."

Comment: Seems like you just need to initialize `var repeat` to `"Y"`.

Comment: Try rephrasing your requirements -- "If my time is valid, I want to ...." then you might restructure your conditional logic and find the answer to your question.

Comment: @Emily Have you learned about the use of debuggers yet? If you walked through your code line by line I think you would see your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `while` condition is failing. If the user enters a non value input then the continue gets hit and your code jumps down to evaluate the condition `while (repeat == 'Y')`

At this point repeat equals null because the prompt that changes it was never called.

Since `null != 'Y'` your loop ends

Comment: And why even have the continue?